# Google Earth Engine, ui.select error in full screen mode

Tags: google-earth-engine

i have an example code from GEE guide:

```
var places = {
  MTV: [-122.0849, 37.3887],
  PEK: [116.4056, 39.9097],
  ZRH: [8.536, 47.376]
  };

var select = ui.Select({
  items: Object.keys(places),
  onChange: function(key) {
     Map.setCenter(places[key][0], places[key][1]);
  }
});

// Set a place holder.
select.setPlaceholder('Choose a location...');

Map.add(select)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/32ec3164251f05fd9870d3d624b535cd

ui.select widget is working in code editor. In full screen mode, ui.select isn't working. I test it with gee app, same error is occurred

https://mynet34.users.earthengine.app/view/ztestapp

Can you help me please?

Comment: I'd file a bug report on this. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=184406&template=1254745

Comment: Thank you Daniell